# Six-story card castle problems with general term

Tags: sequences-and-series

First of all sorry if i am mistaking word translation, i am not a native English speaker.

I got a problem which i partially solved.
I must do calculations with a six-story card castle (two-dimensional pyramid of cards making triangles), and to simplify i think i already solved the general term, i got four possibilities, which i think all right:

Pn = to n, index=1 -> Σ(3n)-n

Pn = to n, index=1 -> Σ(2n) + to n-1, index=1 -> Σ(1)

Pn = (n*(n+1)/2)*3-n and

Pn = 1.5n²  + 0.5n

Are them all right to calculate the cards used knowing the height of this?
[image: castle of cards]

Now i need to know with one of the formulas to know where will it cross a multiple of 52. In another words, i need to know when will the division of them by 52 result in an integer.

I need a justification, not a solution. How am i supposed to reach the solution?

Thanks

Comment: Is Pn supposed to be the number of cards in a triangle of height $n$?  It seems so.  I agree then that Pn$=\frac 12(3n^2+n)$

Comment: That’s an impressive card castle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know when $52$ divides $\frac 12(3n^2+n)$, you can say you want $104$ to divide $n(3n+1)$  You need to account for all the factors of $104$, which are $2^3\cdot 13$  As $n$ and $3n+1$ are of opposite parity, one of them must be divisible by $8$ and one must be divisible by $13$.  This gives four possibilities:  $$ \begin {array}{c|c}\\ n \pmod {104}&3n+1 \pmod {104}\\0&1\\69&0\\13&40\\56&65\end{array}$$  The last two come from applying the [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) to $n\equiv 0 \pmod {13}, n\equiv 5 \pmod 8$ and $n \equiv 0 \pmod 8, n \equiv 4 \pmod{13}$

The smallest positive solution is then $n=13, \frac12(3n^2+n)=260$

Comment: Well, you answer is right, and i made what i could to understand it, but since I didn't knew what were "mod's", "Chinese remainder theorem's" , and how how you've had 8 and 13 from, I've spent some time with my Math teacher to understand it. Yet i don't understand how you made those two columns and get 8 and 13 from. I only have the 11St grade yet :/

Comment: @Claudiop:  You might look at [Wikipedia on modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) to see what the mods are about. The prime factorization of $n(3n+1)$  will be the product of the factorization of $n$ and that of $3n+1$.  Since one is odd and the other even, the even one has to be a multiple of $8$.  One of them (maybe the same one) has to be a multiple of $13$  The first line in my table is when $n$ is a multiple of $104$, the second when $3n+1$ is a multiple of $104$, the third when $n$ is a multiple of $13$ and $3n+1$ a multiple of $8$ and the last

Comment: when $n$ is a multiple of $8$ and $3n+1$ a multiple of $13$